# Jquery extend or bind

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im not sure which i need to use, .bind() or .extend and how do I use it?

I have two checkboxes and once they are clicked if they are checked then a process is called. I also have button that once it is clicked it will check both checkboxes and carry out the functions of the checked checkboxes

```
$('#check1').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        // do stuff for check one only
    }else{
        // undo stuff
    }
});

$('#check2').click(function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        // do stuff for check two only
    }else{
        // undo stuff
    }
});

$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#check1, #check2').prop('checked', true);
    // also carry out the functional ifs from other clicks
});
```

Comment: you should take a look at this article http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/08/04/commonly-confused-bits-of-jquery/

Comment: inside the `click` function, the `this` is the host object, not a 
jQuery Object. http://api.jquery.com/click/
And even more, you have a syntax error on your code.

Comment: that is change not click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand why you would like to use extend here, because this has nothing to do with your question. You should as suggested use change event instead and trigger it for matched set of elements once you have changed programatically their property:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vu63Q/)

```
$('#check1').change(function(){
    if(this.checked){
        // do stuff for check one only
        console.log(this,this.checked);
    }else{
        // undo stuff
    }
});

$('#check2').change(function(){
    if(this.checked){
        // do stuff for check two only
        console.log(this,this.checked);
    }else{
        // undo stuff
    }
});

$('#btn').click(function(){
    $('#check1, #check2').prop('checked', true).change();
    // shortcut for:  $('#check1, #check2').prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
    // or  sometimes better, no bubbling: $('#check1, #check2').prop('checked', true).triggerHandler('change');
});
```

Comment: After I click the button the two checks will check then i want the functions inside to run

Comment: And then this is how to do it, check jsFiddle

Comment: Ah yes sorry, wasnt running console. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**check the fiddle:**

**http://jsfiddle.net/LpSxS/1/**

**example Html:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" id="check1">I have a bike<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Car" id="check2">I have a car<br/> 
<button id="btn">checkboth</button>
```

**jquery:**

```
$('#check1').on("change",function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        alert("checked");
    }else{
        alert("unchecked");
    }
});

$('#check2').on("change",function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        alert("checked")
    }else{
       alert("unchecked")
    }
});

$('#btn').on("click",function(){
    $('#check1, #check2').prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
    // also carry out the functional ifs from other clicks
});
```

Comment: but here you are not triggering onchange event, isn't it the question? At least, this is how i understand it

Comment: i am doing change event for first 2 and last one is button so click event as per his question

Comment: when you click button, checkboxes are checked but their respective change event are not fired

Answer (score 1):

Use `change` instead of `click`. You need to use [trigger('change')](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/), if you want to execute change event

```
$('#check1').on("change",function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        alert("checked");
    }else{
        alert("unchecked");
    }
});

$('#check2').on("change",function(){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        alert("checked")
    }else{
       alert("unchecked")
    }
});

$('#btn').on("click",function(){
    $('#check1, #check2').prop('checked', true).trigger('change');
    // also carry out the functional ifs from other clicks
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle: http://jsbin.com/eJUFinA/2/edit

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#check1').change(function () {
     if(this.checked) {
       //code to checkbox1 checked.
     } else {
       //code to checkbox1 unchecked.
     }
  });
  $('#check2').change(function () {
     if(this.checked) {
       //code to checkbox2 checked.
     } else {
       //code to checkbox2 unchecked.
     }
  });
  $('#btn').click(function () {
    var checked = $('#check1, #check2').prop('checked');
    //do your stuff here.
  });
});
```